# SSO Login in Android between two apps

Tags: android, single-sign-on

I have two apps .
If user authenticates itself on app1 and launches app 2 then we want second app to authenticate the user based on login of app 1.
In short we want to bypass login in second app(SSO).

One way to achieve it is through content provider.
Is there any other way to achieve this on android.